# I am implementing a Minimum Spanning Forrest algorithm in Java. But stuck on how to write a loop

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-algorithm

Algorithm:

**input :** Graph G

**output:** Set of MSTs T

**begin**

T=null;
E=G.Edges;

for all vertices in G,
Create a tree t having single vertex b

add t to T

end for

```
 repeat
    Find an edge e ∈ E having minimum weight
    such that one end belongs to t ∈ T and the other
    end does not belongs to any of the trees in T
    Add e to t
  until e = NULL
```

I'm stuck on the logic for the highlighted block.
I've used simple objects for vertex,edge and tree. And for their sets, used array of Objects.

I have the code:

```
      Tree[] findMSF(){
   T=new Tree[numofMST];
   E=new Edge[C.v.length];
   for(int i=0;i<E.length;i++){
       E[i]=C.e[i];//E ← C.Edges
   }
   for(int i=0;i<B.length;i++){

       t=new Tree(B[i].v);//Create a tree t having single vertex b
       T[i]=t;// T ← T U t

   }

   do{
     e=find_e(E);

   }while(e!=null);

    return T;
    }
```

I need implementation for find_e(E);

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop.

`for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
  Your code
}`
To change the number of times it repeats, change 10 to another number.

Comment: I know how a loop is implemented. But I need the comparison logic for the block